# Waiting after modifying a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get a website to do the following on a button press:

Add a Div (child) into another Div (parent), then wait three seconds and clear the parent. Whatever I do, the child will not be shown in the parent while waiting.

If I remove the part where I clear the parent it will first wait and then show the child. Only if I remove the wating part it will show the child instantly.

This looks to me like I am misunderstanding asynchronous waiting via Ajax but I don't see where I am wrong. Help is appreciated.

Minimal "working" example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EDGE">

<title>Classify</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="loaderStyle.css">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">



function mocktimeout(q)
{
    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "<div class=\"loader\"> </div>";   

    waitfor(
    function setQuality(){
    quality = q;    
    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "";} );

}



function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

function waitfor(callback) {
    wait(3000);
    onAjaxSuccess: (function(){
        callback();
    })();
}

</script>



</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="mainwrapper">

    <div class="main">

        <div id="input" contenteditable="true" class="input"">


        </div>

        <div class="classwrapper">  
            <div id="class1" class="class left">
            </div>



    <button class="btn" onclick="mocktimeout(1)">  </button>

    </div>  


 </div>

</div>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the "wait(3000);" and "onAjaxSuccess: (function()..." you will wait that time running in a loop. 
You should probably use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) after you get the ajax result or before depending if you want to wait first or after you do the ajax call.

Comment: Thank you. I believed that Ajax would run asynchronously anyway. Was that a wrong assumption?

Comment: the ajax will run async, but you were waiting before you made that call

Answer (score 1):

A far easier solution could be using setTimeout() like this:

```
function mocktimeout(timeout) { // timeout in ms for example: 3000
    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "<div class=\"loader\"> </div>";   

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "";
    }, timeout)
}

mocktimeout(3000)
```

Comment: Thank you for adding to the answer. Your code works and I would have accepted it - if it wasn't for another user beeing faster.